# setting a session for a checkbox without $_POST (AJAX?)

Tags: php, session, opencart

I am working on an ecommerce solution using opencart, that has a bunch of checkboxes in order to batch update.

This field is a custom field and what I'm looking to do, is when the user selects these and then continues shopping when they return, they are checked.

I have the following code:

```
<input class="something" type="checkbox" value="£11.75" name="vat[]">
<input class="something" type="checkbox" value="£25.75" name="vat[]">
```

So when the first one is checked, it needs to be added to the session.

How woukd I do this? Could I use javascript/jquery to do an Ajax post to a script that would set the session for each checkbox?

Thanks

Comment: I would go with your solution. Change value with ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use something like this

```
$('input.something').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'http://...',
      data: {'checkbox' : this.value }
      ...
   });
});
```

however, you should ask yourself if it's really required that every change in a checkbox be immediately sent to the server. Does checking off `£11.75` mean that other tabs/windows on the site must be aware of that change? If it's just to update a shopping cart, then wait until the user's done making their changes, THEN send the current values to the server in-bulk. Otherwise you're just using up bandwidth and server resources for no good reason.

Comment: +1 for collating multiple changes into one call. Can I suggest using the 'change' instead of the 'click' event though?

Comment: @Gus: technically, a click on a checkbox IS a change event, since the click will invert the box's state.

Comment: How would I do it with a single call for multiple changes? The chances are they'll only be 2-3 products in the cart a once.

Comment: Have an update button the user can click, which then calls a routine that pulls the checkbox states out of the form and sends to the server all at once.

Comment: What happens though if the user selects the checkboxes and forgets to click the 'Update' and goes to the product page again? These values will be lost.

Comment: You can have an onclick handler register that they've done a change (just a flag = true). in an onbeforeunload, check if the flag's true and prompt them to save/abandon. The converse of your question is "what if they clicked by mistake and didn't want to make that change"?

Comment: That is a valid point. I will investigate doing it as a bulk change